# How can i validate a special type array input using jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, html, validation

**Here is my my form input:**
I will have multiple, i want to validate all dynamically!

```
  <input type="number" name="bill[1][amount]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter bill amount">
```

**And here is my jquery code:**

```
$("#bulkForm").validate({
            rules:
                 {
                  "bill[][amount]":
                          {
                             number: true,
                             required: true
                          }
                 },

                 submitHandler: function(form) {

                    var params = $("#bulkForm").serialize();

 });
```

Comment: Hi @Wiki Babu, pls upload your full form, i will solve it

Comment: Please read [mcve] to complete your question, what you tried, and what you are blocked on, the error or issue you encounter, ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy2gB/10/

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution, if you've dynamic input and validate each input

```js
$(function(){
 $("#bulkForm").validate();
        $("[name^=bill]").each(function(){
     $(this).rules("add", {
          required: true,
         number: true,
         messages: {
             required: "Please enter number"
          }
       });   
     });
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <form action="" id="bulkForm" >
    <input type="text" name="bill[1][amount]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter bill amount">
    <br><input type="text" name="bill[2][amount]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter bill amount">
    <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm wondering where can i submit the form. Please add submitHandler code as well!